# Fail2ban ipset - which conf to use?

Tags: nginx, iptables, fail2ban

I have read that iptables can be slow in case of large number of ip addresses and ipset is more preferred in that scenario. I would like to use ipset banaction but there are at least 3 of them, `iptables-ipset-proto4.conf, iptable-ipset-proto6.conf, iptables-ipset-proto6-allports.conf`, so which one to use?

**OS: Ubuntu server 20.04

Webserver: Nginx

Fail2ban: 0.11.1

Ipset: 7.5**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those actions are:

- `iptables-ipset-proto6` - multi-port action (can ban IP for single or multiple ports)
- `iptables-ipset-proto6-allports` - allports action (bannig IP for all ports)
- `iptables-ipset-proto4` - old action for ipset before v6.14

To use it compatible to `iptable` actions behaviour, you can set it in your `jail.local` in default section (overwritting defaults of [jail.conf](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/4fe4ac8dde6ba14841da598ec37f8c6911fe0f64/config/jail.conf#L208-L209)) like here:

```ini
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6
banaction_allports = iptables-ipset-proto6-allports
```

Comment: There's a small mistake in the jail.local example, you missed a S.
It should be "banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6"

But thanks for the comment, very useful to me !